# Puppet parser fails with custom nodes

Tags: validation, parsing, puppet

I have a puppet manifest (site.pp) which at this point has very basic information. What I am trying to accomplish is a case statement using the node Resource Type in puppet and I cant seem to get it to work 
here is what I have in my site.pp (/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp)

```
cat site.pp
node 'rhel7-pp-agt2' {
        include apache,
}
```

This is the error message I get when I try to validate:

```
puppet parser validate site.pp

Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '}' (file: /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp, line: 3, column: 1)
```

Here is my very basic apache module and its init.pp file

cat ../modules/apache/manifests/init.pp

```
class apache {

include apache::install,
        apache::service,
        apache::config
}
```

My puppet server version is 5.5.0 and puppet agent version is 3.8.7

```
[root@pegasus manifests]# puppet master --version
5.5.0

[root@rhel7-wcc-2 ~]# puppet agent --version
3.8.7
```

Any tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I have been following a course on youtube and I followed exactly what they are doing, so I can atleast get a basic usecase working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the "," after the include lines in the site.pp file and that resolved the parser errors. Now even if I have something like this, my nodes aren't applying the configuration:

        node default {
                include x11packages
    
        
        node 'rhel7-pp-agt2.rmt.com' {
        user {'testuser':
                ensure => present
                }
        }
        node 'rhel7-wcc-1.rmt.com' {
        
        user {'test1234':
                ensure => present,
                groups => ['users','wheel'],
                }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the comma after the include in site.pp? I imagine that is the source of your syntax error.

```
cat site.pp
node 'rhel7-pp-agt2' {
        include apache
}
```

[Documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_node_definitions.html)

Comment: Hi Stefan, yes I did that just now and the parsing works, however none of my agents pickup the new configuration now. It is as though there is nothing to change. I even deleted the testuser and ran puppet agent -t but it didn't apply any new configuration. I verified that by checking if the testuser id got created and it did not.

Comment: Should the nodes be before the default node?

Comment: It sounds like this worked for you, if it did please accept it. It sounds like the second part of your problem should be a second question.